# Respuesta automática según selección de Formulario

Tags: php

Lo que pasa es que tengo un formulario para solicitar el precio de unos paquetes, el formulario pide el `Email`, `teléfono` y Seleccionar el `Paquete` del que se desea saber el precio.

Actualmente al enviar el formulario se recibe una respuesta automática con la información de los precios de todos los paquetes, lo que deseo es que si selecciono el paquete 1, me envíe una respuesta automática con el precio de dicho paquete, si selecciono el paquete 2 me envíe el precio del paquete 2 y así con los 4 paquetes que tengo.

¿Qué es lo que tengo que modificar en mi código `PHP` actual?

```
<?php
if(substr(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 0, 11) == "imEmailForm") {
    include '../res/x5engine.php';
    $form = new ImForm();
    $form->setField('E-Mail', @$_POST['imObjectForm_15_1'], '', false);
    $form->setField('Telefono', @$_POST['imObjectForm_15_2'], '', false);
    $form->setField('Paquetes', @$_POST['imObjectForm_15_3'], '', false);

    if(@$_POST['action'] != 'check_answer') {
        if(!isset($_POST['imJsCheck']) || $_POST['imJsCheck'] != '134CDE4350D57ECB9DCD2DC03951659F' || (isset($_POST['imSpProt']) && $_POST['imSpProt'] != ""))
            die(imPrintJsError());
        $form->mailToOwner('sonoraudio@sonoraudio.com.mx', 'sonoraudio@sonoraudio.com.mx', 'Precios', '', true);
        $form->mailToCustomer('sonoraudio@sonoraudio.com.mx', $_POST['imObjectForm_15_1'], 'Precios', 'Gracias por ponerte en contacto con SonorAudio Los precios de nuestros paquetes son los siguientes:
Paquete 1 - $4,900.00
Paquete 2 - $5,700.00
Paquete 3 - $7,500.00
Paquete 4 - $8,900.00
Atte.
SonorAudio', true);
        @header('Location: ../aviso-de-privacidad.html');
        exit();
    } else {
        echo $form->checkAnswer(@$_POST['id'], @$_POST['answer']) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es tener los paquetes en una fuente de datos seleccionable, por ejemplo en un array. Ahora mismo lo que haces es enviar un string con todos los paquetes:

```
$form->mailToCustomer(
    'sonoraudio@sonoraudio.com.mx', 
    $_POST['imObjectForm_15_1'], 
    'Precios', 
    'Gracias por ponerte en contacto con SonorAudio Los precios de nuestros paquetes son los siguientes:
    Paquete 1 - $4,900.00
    Paquete 2 - $5,700.00
    Paquete 3 - $7,500.00
    Paquete 4 - $8,900.00
    Atte.
    SonorAudio', 
    true
);
```

**Por pasos...**

1.Extraer el mensaje a una variable:

```
$msj = 'Gracias por ponerte en contacto con SonorAudio.
  Los precios de nuestros paquetes son los siguientes:
    Paquete 1 - $4,900.00
    Paquete 2 - $5,700.00
    Paquete 3 - $7,500.00
    Paquete 4 - $8,900.00
    Atte.
    SonorAudio';
$form->mailToCustomer(
    'sonoraudio@sonoraudio.com.mx', 
    $_POST['imObjectForm_15_1'], 
    'Precios', 
    $msj, 
    true
);
```

2.Guardar la información de los paquetes en un array y crear una función que devuelva el mensaje:

```
function getMessage(int $selected)
{
    $paquetes = [
        'Paquete 1 - $4,900.00',
        'Paquete 2 - $5,700.00',
        'Paquete 3 - $7,500.00',
        'Paquete 4 - $8,900.00',
    ];

    $msg = 'Gracias por ponerte en contacto con SonorAudio. Los precios de 
        nuestros paquetes son los siguientes:
        Paquete 1 - $4,900.00
        Paquete 2 - $5,700.00
        Paquete 3 - $7,500.00
        Paquete 4 - $8,900.00';


    $paquete = false;
    foreach ($paquetes as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === ($selected - 1)) {
            $paquete = $value;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($paquete) {
        $msg = 'Gracias por ponerte en contacto con SonorAudio. El precio 
        del paquete seleccionado es el siguiente: ' . PHP_EOL . $paquete;
    }


    return $msg . PHP_EOL . 'Atte. SonorAudio';
}

//Esta función tiene que recibir un número de paquete: 1, 2, 3 o 4, en 
//caso contrario se devuelve el mensaje original con el precio de todos 
//los paquetes, por lo que tienes que arreglarte para pasar una de estas 
//opciones segun que selección se hace.

$msj = getMessage($selected);
$form->mailToCustomer(
    'sonoraudio@sonoraudio.com.mx', 
    $_POST['imObjectForm_15_1'], 
    'Precios', 
    $msj, 
    true
);
```